# How do I change the rear lights on Peugeot 307 CC?

Tags: peugeot, tail-lights

How do I change the rear lights on Peugeot 307 CC?

The CC (Coupe) version doesn't seem to have a visible place to open the back light cover.

Comment: Julian Webster was spot on. Changed the number plate bulb and the rear lights work again. Time taken 30 seconds, cost 99p. Brilliant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory repair manual is a bit sketchy about it, but here what it says (translated from Russian version):

- Put the roof in the intermediate position (I suppose, somewhere in the middle between fully open and fully closed).
- Cut out (?) and remove the carpet (1 on the figure). That cutting out bit puzzles me. Maybe, just pull out from under the trim?
- Partially pull out inner lining (2).
- Release the fasteners for the rear light, pull it out, disconnect the harness, then remove it.

[image]

The picture and instructions are rather confusing for someone who had not seen the car in person, but hope this helps. If it does, please, comment here and clarify, so I can edit the post for the next person with the same problem.

Comment: These instructions are for the fender part, let me know if you need those for the trunk lid as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to move the carpet. There's a plastic moulding that when unclipped exposes the fasteners for the light cluster. It's then just a case of releasing the light and replacing with a new unit (they're not cheap though!)

Answer (score 0):

open roof till bonnet sits back,then go no further,at rear on top, small plastic panel pull it off,you will see nylon  thumb screw nut,undo pull light fitting out,reverse process to put back together

Answer (score 0):

If this helps !! Just the outer casing fell off my back light, couldn't find a cheap one, "breakers yards scrap yards" Peugeot wanted £141  + vat lol!!! So in the end I got some "red light tint" off eBay £3.69 !!! Job done !  A little bit fiddly too do, but look at the saving for a hours tinkering.

Comment: This doesn't tell you how to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Open the boot. 
Locate the plastic trim above the roof mechanism on the side you are working. 
Remove the three star bolts. 
Remove trim and the small plastic trim beneath it. 
Remove the plastic ‘nut’ retaining the light cluster. 
Remove light cluster by gently pulling. 
Refitting is reverse of removal.

Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Do not open the roof
is very simple
remove the three screws on plastic covering the roof struts
and then is a plastic cover odds you with a little grommet need to pull it out helping yourself with small flat screwdriver which is on three clips attached to it
You will see it is rear end of the roof rest grommet/ large
then unscrew the brown plastic screw and the light is out
P.S
other end of the light/ facing the front of the car is on clip
easy
If the light is not working check the number plate bulb and if is gone just change it and the leds on rear light will be back working and you don't need the take it off
GOOD LUCK